# How to keep the code running even after the GUI frontend is exited?

Tags: scripts, xterm

I am writing a shell script that runs upon start-up using `xterm` and asks the user to do things I want him to do.

For example, the code is supposed to ask the user to change his password in 1 minute. If the password isn't changed, the script logs out the user.

The problem is that if the user closes the display he will stop the code from being executed. I want to prevent this.

```
oldpass=$(grep $USER /etc/shadow)
echo "you have 1 minute to change your password"
sleep 60
Newpass=$(grep $USER /etc/shadow)
if [[ oldpass == newpass ]] then
  Pkill -u $USER
fi
```

I want to add the condition " *and, if*  `xterm` is closed *then* logout"

Comment: For example the code is supposed to ask the user to change his password in 1 minute and if the password isn't changed after the code logs out of the session the user simply can close the display and end the code I want to prevent that

Comment: Is still unclear.

Comment: I want the code to keep running in background if the user closes the display

Comment: Can you _edit_ your question and add the script?

Comment: You can use two separate instances - one as a daemon that keeps running and one as the interface (CLI or GUI).  The CLI/GUI can be closed all day but the daemon will continue to chug along until that minute runs out and then sends the logout signal.  

Post the code you have for a more specific answer with an example.

You could also replace the user's terminal shell with your script and if they change the password you launch bash/sh/etc as would normally happen.  This would essentially give you complete control of the session in the beginning.

Comment: If I gained complete control the user won't be able to close the display??

Comment: You mean it should be `if (oldpass==newpass)|(xterm is killed) then kill user` (no pun intended). It should be OR not AND.

Comment: I know it is or not and but how to say xterm is killed??

Comment: You can probably do `ps -A | grep xterm` to check if xterm is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to look at `byobu` or `screen` for this. Then you can close the terminal window and the shell is still running. Afterwards, you can connect back to it. This is also useful when you want to connect to it from a different machine using ssh. That is very popular with IRC clients, for instance.

Comment: this is what I was looking for thanks I will try it :)